# How to safety save password in env file - Laravel

Tags: laravel

Example of SMPT confign in env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.XXX.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxx_username
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx_password
```

In the project, I will save the API token or password in the env file.
But it's not a safety solution. Because everyone can touch my password.
What is safety solution for save the password?

**Edit:**

Maybe mail config is not good example.

The issue that is all password or API key, not limit to email password.
E.g. database API, payment gateway API, etc

The problem is some user, maybe server maintenance team can login to the server by FTP or font of the server. How to block those team to see the password or API key.

Comment: To secure the password just set the mail configuration in 'mail.php' directly.

Comment: @sachinkumar don't do this, mail.php is a config file and WILL be added to the repo... every developer would be able to see your password.

Comment: what do you mean by everyone can touch your password, usually people don't share .env file

Comment: Some edit of my question

Comment: @Jay Chu I am facing the same problem. Did you find a solution in order to encrypt username, password from smtp email in .env file?

Answer (score 0):

> In the project, I will save the API token or password in the env file. But it's not a safety solution. Because everyone can touch my password. What is safety solution for save the password?

First, if you are sharing your code through a git repo, no one will se your password since the .env file is not added to the repo... and every developer would have to add its own .env file... maybe everyone can have it's own configuration for this so it would be secure.

Unless you are sharing your code in other manner... or that you're afraid of putting that into production in which case, you should not use your own email... every single mail you send will be sent to the trash.

I would not recommend, sending emails from your own email.

Check for services with free tiers like: sparkpost, sendgrid, mailgun, et al.

The recommended ones for laravel would be sparkpost and mailgun.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail

> Laravel provides a clean, simple API over the popular SwiftMailer library with drivers for SMTP, Mailgun, SparkPost, Amazon SES, PHP's mail function, and sendmail, allowing you to quickly get started sending mail through a local or cloud based service of your choice.

Either that, or creating a new specific email account that you don't mind sharing with others...

Also, for developing, you could just use the Log driver which will just log the email instead of really sending it.

Comment: Yes, My env file will not push to git. The file only save in product server. But some user, maybe server maintenance team can login to the server by FTP or font of the server. How block those team to see the password or API

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gmail then you can use App Passwords facility of google. just create app password and use in your application. you can create app many passwords. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en